# Storybook adds a period after http: to all links and scripts in preview-head.html, how to remove this

Tags: javascript, ember.js, storybook

I am using `Storybookjs` with `Emberjs`. When it generates the `preview-head.html` file it adds all the links and scripts in my current `index.html` file but adds a period after the : causing them to not work.

Example of link in preview-head.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:.//s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myapp/styles.css" />
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: No, but try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myapp/styles.css"></link>` - a lot of times the backslash at the end causes issues with many programs.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately that didnt work :(

Comment: Please include your `config/environment.js`.